# Eclipse package explorer does not showing res folder of Android project

Tags: android, package, directory, explorer, invisible

Sometimes the res Folder with the layout and value files disappears in the package exploere view, and i dont know why. 
when i create a new res folder, it shows a message that the res folder already exists.
The only thing i can do is to set a new workspace and import the project again.
Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the setting in your package explorer view caused /res to become hidden, make sure the marked button in the image below is not active:

[image]

Comment: I do not find that button in Eclipse Juno

Comment: Juno is ~3 year-old, the functionality may not have existed back then

Comment: I used the eclipse download for android - I believe this is the latest available. Help|About shows 'Eclipse for Android Developers' ver 23.02  My res folder has disappeared. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824421/deleted-and-recreated-android-res-folder-eclipse-does-not-show-it